# Kafka SASL off domain

Tags: ldap, apache-kafka, kerberos

I have a POC domain in and AWS VPC with a kerberised Kafka cluster operating with SSL.

In the VPC which has Active Directory we can connect producer/consumers to the cluster over `SASL_SSL` and everything works fine.

Part of the POC requires an on-prem service to produce to the broker. I'd hope we could use `LdapLoginModule` in the `jaas.conf` and for now just user LDAP over SSL passing in the password till we got federated AD.

Can someone confirm if this is possible or any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a similar question, it would seem SASL/PLAIN is the way to go http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/sasl.html#authentication-using-sasl-plain